# Looking up key-value pairs in JSON objects from XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an XSLT implementation that hyphenates strings following latex patterns, i.e. inserts soft hyphens in strings. I call this function like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="p[lang('en')]/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:hyphenate(., '­', 'en')"/>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
```

Now, before I call the `hyphenate` function, I would like to consult a list of exceptions. I'm fairly flexible about the format in which I get the exceptions, but I would also like to use this opportunity to learn how to take advantage of json objects from within XSLT 3.0.

So let's say i have a JSON file called `exceptions.json` that looks like this:

```js
{
    "en" :{
       "recognizance": "re-cog-ni-zance",
       "reformation": "ref-or-ma-tion",
       "retribution": "ret-ri-bu-tion",
       "table": "ta-ble"
    },

    "de" : {   
      //etc.   
    }
}
```

(I am not using soft hyphens in the above example because they wouldn't show on Stackoverflow, but that's irrelevant for the question I am asking).

How could I read (and parse?) the contents of the JSON file into a variable called `$exceptions`, so that I could most efficiently do something like:

```xml
  <xsl:template match="p[lang('en')]/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="">
      <!--test if matched string is a key in my json object and return the 
          corresponding value. for instance, if the matched substring here is 
          "table", I'd like to return something like 
          <xsl:value-of select="$exceptions['en']['table']"/> , 
          i.e. "ta-ble", using whatever notation may be correct for this 
          kind of thing. -->
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="fn:hyphenate(., '­', 'en')"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the XPath 3.1 and the XSLT 3.0 specs are online, so you could have found the necessary functions (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-json-doc, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-map-contains) and notations (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-lookup).

Use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="exceptions" select="json-doc('exceptions.json')"/>`, the you can access e.g. `map:contains($exceptions?en, .)` to check whether the current word is in the `en` map.

Example: (reading JSON inline for self-containedness):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p[lang('en')]/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="map:contains($exceptions?en, .)">
      <xsl:sequence select="$exceptions?en(.)"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} at {current-dateTime()}</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-exceptions" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">
{
    "en" :{
       "recognizance": "re-cog-ni-zance",
       "reformation": "ref-or-ma-tion",
       "retribution": "ret-ri-bu-tion",
       "table": "ta-ble"
    }
}    
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:param name="exceptions" select="parse-json($json-exceptions)"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj-saxon-worker/index-workbench.html?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20html-version%3D%225%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22p%5Blang%28%27en%27%29%5D%2Ftext%28%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aanalyze-string%20select%3D%22.%22%20regex%3D%22%5Cw%2B%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amatching-substring%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22map%3Acontains%28%24exceptions%3Fen%2C%20.%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22%24exceptions%3Fen%28.%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amatching-substring%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anon-matching-substring%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Anon-matching-substring%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aanalyze-string%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20at%20%7Bcurrent-dateTime%28%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22json-exceptions%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22en%22%20%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22recognizance%22%3A%20%22re-cog-ni-zance%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22reformation%22%3A%20%22ref-or-ma-tion%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22retribution%22%3A%20%22ret-ri-bu-tion%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22table%22%3A%20%22ta-ble%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22exceptions%22%20select%3D%22parse-json%28%24json-exceptions%29%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Croot%20xml%3Alang%3D%22en%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cp%3EThis%20is%20a%20table.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the JSON to XML, then process it as such.

In your example, this could probably look something like:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:your="your-namespace-here"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="exceptions" select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text('path/to/exceptions.json'))" />

<xsl:key name="excpt" match="fn:string" use="@key" />

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="key('excpt', ., $exceptions)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="if($lookup) then $lookup else your:hyphenate(.)" /> 
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Untested, because you did not provide a reproducible example. Do note that I am using the `fn` prefix as intended by the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#namespace-prefixes); you will need to use another prefix for your own function.